# Why is this variable giving me always the value of 0?

Tags: sensors, c++

I am doing a project and here is the code that I am using, but I do not know why the values of duration and sofia is always 0 so the values of distance and monroy are also 0

```
const int trigPin = 9;
const int echoPin = 10;

const int t = 8;
const int e = 7;

long duration, sofia;
int distance, monroy;
void setup() {
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  pinMode(t, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (e, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
}
void loop() {
  // Clears the trigPin
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite (t, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (t, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite (t, LOW);
  // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  sofia = pulseIn(e, HIGH);
  // Calculating the distance
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
  monroy = sofia * 0.034 / 2;
  Serial.print(duration);
  if (distance = 15);
  {
    digitalWrite (3, HIGH);
    delay (5000);
    digitalWrite (3, LOW);
  }

  if ((monroy >= 0) && (monroy <= 5));
  {
    digitalWrite (4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite (5, LOW);
    digitalWrite (6, LOW);
  }
  if ((monroy >= 5.1) && (monroy <= 9));
  {

    digitalWrite (5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite (6, LOW);
  }
  if (monroy >= 9.1);
  {

    digitalWrite (5, LOW);
    digitalWrite (6, HIGH);
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have the Arduino connected to anything?

Comment: My Arduino is connected to my laptop

Comment: What do you have connected to pins 9 and 10 of your Arduino? You might find this post on our meta site helpful: [How to ask a good question for Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange)

Comment: In the 9th and 10th pins I have the echo and trig pins connected. Thanks!

Comment: Please do a Serial.print of `sofia` so we can see what value is being used for the subsequent calculation.

Comment: when i write Serial.print(sofia) it always prints 0

Comment: It looks like it is timing out after one second, in that case. See: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/pulsein/

Comment: What is connected to pin 7?

Answer (score 4):

When I formatted your code for readability and then compiled it I got these warnings:

```
/tmp/arduino_modified_sketch_71221/sketch_may02a.ino: In function 'void loop()':
/tmp/arduino_modified_sketch_71221/sketch_may02a.ino:34:20: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
   if (distance = 15);
                    ^
/tmp/arduino_modified_sketch_71221/sketch_may02a.ino:34:21: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
   if (distance = 15);
                     ^
/tmp/arduino_modified_sketch_71221/sketch_may02a.ino:41:38: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
   if ((monroy >= 0) && (monroy <= 5));
                                      ^
/tmp/arduino_modified_sketch_71221/sketch_may02a.ino:47:40: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
   if ((monroy >= 5.1) && (monroy <= 9));
                                        ^
/tmp/arduino_modified_sketch_71221/sketch_may02a.ino:53:21: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
   if (monroy >= 9.1);
```

These are **important** - you should pay attention to them. For example, here:

```
  if (distance = 15);  // <-- NO SEMICOLON NEEDED HERE!
  {
    digitalWrite (3, HIGH);
    delay (5000);
    digitalWrite (3, LOW);
  }
```

Putting a semicolon there means that stuff under the `if` is **always executed** - the semicolon terminates the scope of the `if`.

---

To see the warnings open the Preferences dialog in the IDE GUI and change "Compiler warnings" to "All".

---

Also:

```
  if (distance = 15);
```

This **assigns** 15 to distance, so distance will always be 15. You mean:

```
  if (distance == 15)
```